# Why does the below file generation method return FileNotFoundException on simultaneous request to this endpoint?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, file-io, qr-code, scalability

I have written an endpoint to return a zip containing multiple qr with values based on the details in my database. When I did a load test by making multiple requests to this endpoint, It throws FileNotFoundException. But that doesn't happend if the requests are made at a specific time interval.

```kotlin
@GetMapping(value = ["/{sysId}/code"], produces = ["application/zip"])
fun generateQrCode1(@PathVariable sysId: Int): ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> {
    val sysDetails = sysService.getById(sysId)
    val productDetails = productService.getProductByProductId(sysDetails.productId)
    val zipName = sysDetails.productId.toString() + ".zip"
    FileOutputStream(zipName).use { fileOutputStream ->
        ZipOutputStream(fileOutputStream).use { zipOutputStream ->
            for (i in 1..sysDetails.length) {
                val u = "http://" + "$domain/" + "?sysId=${sysId}&pid=$i"
                val x = generateQRCodeWithText(u, 350, 300, arrayOf("QR CODE TEST"))
                val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
                byteArrayOutputStream.write(x!!)
                val zipEntry = ZipEntry(
                    "${
                        productDetails.name
                    }-${sysId}-$i.jpg"
                )
                zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(zipEntry)
                byteArrayOutputStream.writeTo(zipOutputStream)
            }
        }
    }
    try {
        return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"$zipName")
            .body(InputStreamResource(FileInputStream(zipName)))
    } finally {
        java.nio.file.Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(zipName))
    }
  
    fun generateQRCodeWithText(data: String?, width: Int?, height: Int, text: Array<String?>): ByteArray? {
    return try {
        val qrCodeWriter = QRCodeWriter()
        val bitMatrix = qrCodeWriter.encode(data, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, width!!, height)
        val pngOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
        MatrixToImageWriter.writeToStream(bitMatrix, "PNG", pngOutputStream)
        var pngData = pngOutputStream.toByteArray()

        if (text.size > 0) {
            val totalTextLineToadd = text.size
            val `in`: InputStream = ByteArrayInputStream(pngData)
            val image: BufferedImage = ImageIO.read(`in`)
            val outputImage =
                BufferedImage(image.width, image.height + 25 * totalTextLineToadd, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB)
            val g: Graphics = outputImage.graphics
            val g2d = g as Graphics2D
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_FRACTIONALMETRICS, RenderingHints.VALUE_FRACTIONALMETRICS_ON);
            g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            g.setColor(Color.WHITE)
            g.fillRect(0, 0, outputImage.width, outputImage.height)
            g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height, null)
            g.setFont(Font("Arial Black", Font.BOLD, 20))
            val textColor: Color = Color.BLUE
            g.setColor(textColor)
            val fm: FontMetrics = g.getFontMetrics()
            var startingYposition = height + 5
            for (displayText in text) {
                g.drawString(
                    displayText,
                    outputImage.width / 2 - fm.stringWidth(displayText) / 2,
                    startingYposition
                )
                startingYposition += 20
            }
            val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
            ImageIO.write(outputImage, "PNG", baos)
            baos.flush()
            pngData = baos.toByteArray()
            baos.close()
        }
        pngData
    } catch (ex: WriterException) {
        throw ex
    } catch (ex: IOException) {
        throw ex
    }
}
```

Error on multiple requests at same time:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 2889.zip (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
 at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
 at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93) ~[?:1.8.0_292]
 at com.mangoChain.qrApi.QrApi.generateQrCode1(QrApi.kt:136) ~[classes!/:?]
```

Comment: `generateQrCode1` isn’t thread-safe. Multiple requests for the same sysId will result in multiple threads creating and deleting the same zip file.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson I have added it ! getById() ,getProductById() is a call to db  which is not causing the issue, as I have checked it separately.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my earlier comment as I realised that it’s `generateQrCode1` that isn’t thread-safe.

Comment: @VeerabalaJ Are multiple requests made with same `sysId`? If not, is it possible that `sysService.getById(sysId)` with 2 different `sysId` returns the same `productId`? As Andy said, if multiple threads deal with files with the same name, they could delete each other's files.

Comment: Also, as a side note, you're missing a closing double-quote for the filename in the Content-Disposition header

Comment: @Joffrey Yes there is a high possibility for sysService.getById(sysId)  to return  same productId for different sysId . Is there a standard approach to do this in a proper way?

Comment: @VeerabalaJ You should just make sure your filename is unique, so if `sysId` is always different, but `productId` can collide, you could name your files based on `sysId` instead of (or in addition to) `productId`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure your local filename (`zipName`) is unique, because otherwise multiple threads could delete each other's files.

You mentioned in the comments that `productId` can collide, so you could name your files based on `sysId` instead of (or in addition to) `productId`. For instance:

```kotlin
val zipName = "$sysId-${sysDetails.productId}.zip"
```

Note that you only need to make your local filename unique (`zipName`), but you can still keep what you want for the user-visible filename in `Content-Disposition` header:

```kotlin
return ResponseEntity
    .ok()
    .header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"${sysDetails.productId}.zip\"")
    .body(InputStreamResource(FileInputStream(zipName)))
```

As a side note to this, you should probably use a temporary folder instead of just a plain filename, because currently these files are created in the current workdir.